# Erlang: function with variable from another scope

Tags: list, erlang, erl

Please, help me to write correctly function on Erlang. Function should remove packages (which successfully sent) from the queue. I think it should be like that, but it does not work. Erlang says: illegal pattern on line 3 :(

```
delete_pkts(AcksList, State) ->
  NewSendingList = lists:filter(fun(X) ->
    lists:any(fun(E) -> case E of X#internal_packet.message_number -> false; _ -> true end end, AcksList)
  end, State#state.pkt_send),
  State#state{ pkt_send = NewSendingList }.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never understood why, but you can't put a record field reference in a case clause.  You could match out the field you're interested in in the function head instead:

```
delete_pkts(AcksList, State) ->
  NewSendingList = lists:filter(fun(#internal_packet{message_number = MsgNo}) ->
    lists:any(fun(E) -> case E of MsgNo -> false; _ -> true end end, AcksList)
  end, State#state.pkt_send),
  State#state{ pkt_send = NewSendingList }.
```

Alternatively, as the `case` expression just returns `false` if `E` matches, and `true` otherwise, you could use the `=/=` operator:

```
delete_pkts(AcksList, State) ->
  NewSendingList = lists:filter(fun(X) ->
    lists:any(fun(E) -> E =/= X#internal_packet.message_number end, AcksList)
  end, State#state.pkt_send),
  State#state{ pkt_send = NewSendingList }.
```

Comment: Assuming for example message_number being the second field in record internal packet X#internal_packet.message_number is synonymous with element(3, X) and that is a function call which isn't allowed either in a clause